# Optaplanner - Local search phase terminated without picking a nextStep

Tags: optaplanner

I ran into a situation where only two valid moves that is allowed happens during the construction phase. This results in a situation where there is no valid moves to perform during local search phase. All the moves tried during the local search phase is not doable.

This results in `NullPointerException` at the end of local search phase.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.scope.DefaultSolverScope.getBestScoreWithUninitializedPrefix(DefaultSolverScope.java:205)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.outerSolvingEnded(DefaultSolver.java:216)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:161)
at com.example.jobplanner.Application.main(Application.java:328)
```

Here is the trace of the two valid moves that happens during the construction phase.

```
CH step (0), time spent (151), score (0hard/0soft), selected move count (1), picked move (com.example.jobplanner.domain.ServiceJobChip@981500 => com.example.jobplanner.domain.ShopFloorBay@9da471).
Update [fact 0:5:4216052:4216052:10:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:com.example.jobplanner.domain.ServiceJobChip@4054f4]


CH step (1), time spent (158), score (0hard/0soft), selected move count (1), picked move (com.example.jobplanner.domain.ServiceJobChip@4054f4 => com.example.jobplanner.domain.ShopFloorBay@15ac5d5).
Construction Heuristic phase (0) ended: step total (2), time spent (159), best score (null).
```

The model of the domain I am trying to optimize would be something like:

- Each bay has --> set of tasks that can be performed
- Job -> collection of tasks to be performed
- Task --> can be scheduled to bays which can perform the task

Comment: Looks like a bug. Please [create an issue in Jira](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER) and clearly mention the version you're using.

Comment: Jira issue created.
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-266